# How can I exclude the lines which matche the range patterns in sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am writing `sed` expression which tries to print the text within a range of patterns:

```
apt-cache showpkg gdm | sed -n '/Reverse Depends:/,/Dependencies:/ p'
```

This basically works, current output is:

```
Reverse Depends: 
  libgdm1:i386,gdm 3.8.3-3~
  ...
  ...
  gnome-control-center-data,gdm 3.0
Dependencies:
```

But I don't want the lines containing the patterns themselves, I want:

```
  libgdm1:i386,gdm 3.8.3-3~
  ...
  ...
  gnome-control-center-data,gdm 3.0
```

I know I can just just pipe the output to `grep` with `-v` option:

```
grep -v "Reverse Depends:"
```

But I hope `sed` has an option for it. I have tried

```
$ apt-cache showpkg gdm | sed -n '/Reverse Depends:/-1,/Dependencies:/-1 p'
```

But it doesn't work:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown command: `-'
```

Comment: @don_crissti That's excellent. Post that as an answer with a brief explanation of how it works! I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete everything between the first line and the first pattern, between the second pattern and the last line:

```
apt-cache showpkg gdm | sed '1,/Reverse Depends:/d;/Dependencies:/,$d'
```

Note that this approach will fail if your first pattern occurs on the first line and [doing regexes checking more than is necessary can affect performance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257084/38906).

A better approach:

```
$ apt-cache showpkg gdm |
  sed -n '/Reverse Depends:/{
    :1
    n
    /Dependencies:/q
    p
    b1
  }'
```

Comment: ah I wish I thought of that, thanks cuonglm! I will accept when stackexchange lets me :)

Comment: To get this to work I actually had to use `apt-cache showpkg gdm | sed '1,/Reverse Depends:/d' | sed '/Dependencies:/,$d'` for some reason it didnt work for me otherwise - using GNU sed. but the basic idea worked

Comment: @the_velour_fog: Please paste exact the command you run. I tried GNU sed without any issue.

Comment: - when I used your command in a bash script and added a variable and redirected output to a file I was having problems - but now its working fine - so it obviously was my mistake!