# Extract lines between two match strings while excluding the matched lines

Tags: awk, sed, files, pattern-matching

Below is my file

```
$ cat README
login user1
run .profile
cd /u/opt
unzip -l zip file
copy files in zip file to .orig
unzip -o the zip file
cd /u/opt/install
./reqe21.sh
sqlplus admin/<password> @req.sql
logout
```

I need lines between the matched string last `unzip` and `logout` i.e desired output is below

```
cd /u/opt/install
./reqe21.sh
sqlplus admin/<password> @req.sql
```

I need a couple of answers.

1. When I tried `sed -n '/unzip -o /,/logout/p' README` it does not exclude the matching lines.

Thus, I get the below output:

```
unzip -o the zip file
cd /u/opt/install
./reqe21.sh
sqlplus admin/<password> @req.sql
logout
```

I tried another solution given here: [How can I exclude the lines which matche the range patterns in sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257476/how-can-i-exclude-the-lines-which-matche-the-range-patterns-in-sed)

But, I do not get the desired output. See below:

```
$ sed '1,/unzip/d;/logout/,$d' README
copy files in zip file to .orig
unzip -o the zip file
cd /u/opt/install
./reqe21.sh
sqlplus vrcadmin/<password> @req.sql
```

2. How do I use `sed` so that I get the lines between last `unzip` and the last `logout` i.e the desired output as was shared before.

Comment: @Quasímodo  No. I tried the solution and it does not give me the desired results. Updated my Question as well. Please check

Comment: Yes, it does, as long as you keep the whole initial pattern you had tried. `sed '1,/unzip -o /d;/logout/,$d'`

Comment: It answers my question partially. i.e when I give `unzip -o ` However, how can I get it to consider the last unzip line when I simply give `unzip` and not `unzip -o` ?

Comment: That is a different question. For those additional complications, I'd use Awk or feed Sed the file from upside down with Tac.

Answer (score 4):

This simply isn't a job that sed is best for. Try this:

```
$ tac file | awk '/unzip/{exit} f; /logout/{f=1}' | tac
cd /u/opt/install
./reqe21.sh
sqlplus admin/<password> @req.sql
```

or if you prefer to use just one tool for some reason:

```
$ awk '/logout/{f=0} f{rec=rec $0 ORS} /unzip/{rec=""; f=1} END{printf "%s", rec}' file
cd /u/opt/install
./reqe21.sh
sqlplus admin/<password> @req.sql
```

Comment: You can also do it with yourself, Ed! `echo '?unzip?+1,?logout?-1p' | ed -s file` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Inverting the input and then running sed on it. Using the range operator we select the block and then trim the boundaries by reapplying the same regex.

```
$ tac |
sed -e '/logout/,/unzip/!d;//!d' |
tac
cd /u/opt/install
./reqe21.sh
sqlplus admin/<password> @req.sql
```

---

Or, if we want the result w/o any other utility. we keep accumulating the block (bounded by unzip and logout) in the hold space. Then overwrite hold if we see an unzip line again.Th7s will get us the last unzip to logout bounded block. Then we clip the boundaries.This is all Posixly sed

```
sed -e '
  /\n/{
    P;/\n.*\n/D;d
  }
  /unzip/,/logout/!d
  H;/unzip/h;/logout/!d
  g;D
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tac filename| awk '/logout/{f=1}/unzip/{f=0}f && !/logout/'|tac
```

output

```
cd /u/opt/install
./reqe21.sh
sqlplus admin/<password> @req.sql
```